# Download csv file from JAX-RS using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, csv, download, jax-rs

I am using Angular JS in client side and Jax-Rs in server side. I send a path from server side of a csv file. 
How can i download it from client side?

my path send from server side.

http://localhost:8080/MyProject/generatereport/de6c85d5-ac1d-438c-93ee-8dcb23397bdf.CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Path("/file")
public class FileService {

    private static final String FILE_PATH = "c:\\file.csv";

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces("text/csv")
    public Response getFile() {

        File file = new File(FILE_PATH);

        ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
        response.header("Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename=\"file_from_server.csv\"");
        return response.build();

    }

}
```

That should work.